# mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-jammy-chiseled: not found

Tags: c#, docker

I have created the default WeatherForecast web api project with Docker support.
By default, the dockerfile is using aspnet: 6.0

But I would like to upgrade it to `6.0-jammy-chiseled`. This is my dockerfile after I have updated it to `6.0-jammy-chiseled`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-jammy-chiseled AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-jammy-chiseled AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Weather2.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./Weather2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Weather2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Weather2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Weather2.dll"]
```

When I run it, I got an error:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-jammy-chiseled: not found
```

I try to pull the image manually with `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:6.0-jammy-chiseled` and it pull without issue.

Comment: When you test locally, you pull from `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet`, but your Dockerfile pulls from `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet`. Notice how you're missing `nightly` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: you mean my sdk is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0` while my run time is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:6.0-jammy-chiseled`? I also try to add `nightly`, it still failed. Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "tail": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: No, not your SDK. I meant the runtime, you know, on the first line of your Dockerfile? `jammy-chiseled` is a preview image, it's not on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet`, it's on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet`.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What is your Dockerfile now?

Comment: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:6.0-jammy-chiseled AS base
...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-jammy AS build

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [Docker file of the official sample app](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/aspnetapp/Dockerfile.chiseled), I think that your Docker file should be revised as

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:6.0-jammy-chiseled AS base` (add `nightly` in the image path)

and

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-jammy AS build` (remove `-chiseled` as SDK has no need to be chiseled and Microsoft will not publish chiseled SDK but only chiseled runtime.

Comment: still got error:  Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "tail": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: It is saying that the `tail` is not found. Could you show which docker build step you hit this error, and check if `tail` is available or not in your build server?

Comment: How do I check which docker build step hit the error? How do I check the `tail`? when I run `docker ps`, there is nothing there.

Comment: When you run `docker build`, you should see output likes this: 
Step 1/17 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:6.0-jammy-chiseled AS b                                                                                                                      ase 
Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app Step 3/17 : EXPOSE 80 .... Or the build just failed without even showing "Step1"?

Comment: The tail command missing is a runtime issue, not a build issue.  I'm also running into this issue, and I'm not sure which step in the docker process adds the tail command, but the command is required to keep a .NET application actively running in the container.  The only thing I can think of is to copy the tail executable from the 6.0-jammy image and add it into the final stage that uses 6.0-jammy-chiseled.